# String representation in c#

Tags: c#, string

im tring to  grab some text from existing  webpage using  this method :

```
  try
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            result = client.DownloadString(url);
            int start = result.IndexOf("startpointstr") ;

            end = result.IndexOf("EndpointStr");

            result = result.Substring(start, end - start);
          string.Format(
            MessageBox.Show(result);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle error
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

in the positive side  it works for english 
but for languages like Hebrew 
it returns   unrecognised  chars (not an hebrew language )
is there a way to reformat the returned string ?

Comment: you'll need to know what encoding the web page is using - it should tell you this in the HTML headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [WebClient.Encoding Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding.aspx) to set the resource's encoding.

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to know the encoding of the page that you are downloading before converting it to a string. Some candidates to check would be in order of precedence:

1. HTTP Content-Type of the response (*charset* attribute value)
2. http-equiv META tag (*charset* attribute value)
3. BOM of the returned stream ([Byte Order Mark](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html))
4. UTF-8 as default value

Note that not all web pages are encoded with UTF-8, especially outside of the western hemisphere.